how to add an additional dll to an exe file and force it to use
I have an exe file in which I want to make some corrections to the binary code, but I want to do this not just by editing bytes but by using an additional dll, which should patch the current executable file when launched.
How can I force the executable file to use an additional dll once before launching?
I tried adding a dll to the executable file through the StudPE program, but the program does not use the added dll

Even DLLs have entry-points, usually called DllMain. The entry-point is called when the DLL is loaded (among other events). You got a chance to do something then.
